# Why does "kubectl apply" merge deployment descriptors after rollback

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

I am using Azure Kubernetes Services with K8S version 1.20.9 and have following K8S deployment

Version 1:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: busybox-deployment
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: 
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: busybox
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Container 1 is Running ; sleep 3600']
        env:
          - name: KEY_1
            value: VALUE_1
```

I deploy with `kubectl apply` it and check the value of the `KEY_1` environment variable - it is correctly set to `VALUE_1`.

Then I deploy 2 more versions (again via `kubectl apply`) where I change the key-value pair in the env section like this effectively deleting the old environment variable and creating a new one:

Version 2:

```
        env:
          - name: KEY_2
            value: VALUE_2
```

Version 3:

```
        env:
          - name: KEY_3
            value: VALUE_3
```

After each deploy I check the environment variables and they are fine - version 2 contains the `KEY_2:VALUE_2` pair and version 3 contains the `KEY_3:VALUE_3` pair.

Now I rollback to version 2 by invoking

```
kubectl rollout undo deployment ...
```

This is also correctly working and now we have the `KEY_2:VALUE_2` pair as environment variables.

However, if I deploy version 3 again the container and the deployment descriptor have both the `KEY_2:VALUE_2` and the `KEY_3:VALUE` as environment variables. This matches none of the deployed descriptors because they always contain only a single environment variable.
Subsequent deployments result in the same behavior until I manually edit and delete the unnecessary property.

I read some explanations like [this nice article](https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-apply-replace-patch/) where it is explained that `kubectl apply` would remove old properties, while patch would not.

However this does not happen when "undo" is performed. Any idea why?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of K8s are you using?

Comment: @p10l  it is 1.20.9 on AKS (i.e. managed service). I added this in the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with `rollout undo`, reported here [#94698](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94698), here [#25236](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/25236), and here [#22512](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22512).

In layman terms - `kubectl` incorrectly calculates differences and merges changes, becacuse `undo` does not properly load previous configuration.

More about how K8s calculates differences can be found in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-apply-calculates-differences-and-merges-changes).

Workaround is to update manually last-applied-configuration before re-applying another deployment from config file

```text
kubectl apply set-last-applied -f Deployment_v2.yaml -o yaml
```